# Java how to get specific words in a string (By using substring and indexOf)

Tags: java

For example, I have the color of a shirt, the size&the cost of it. All those informations are in 1 single string, e.g :

> "blue, small, 15, orange, large, 10, green, small, 5"

How can I put all colors/sizes/cost into 1 each new string (String colors,sizes,cost) with `substring` and `indexOf`? The pattern is the same but I have no idea how to skip certain comma when I use `IndexOf("," , starting position)`.

edit: Can't use split

Comment: do you have to use `indexOf` and `substring`? `split` would seem like a better idea

Comment: have you tried `split()` that is easier I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with substring without split.

```
String line="blue, small, 15, orange, large, 10, green, small, 5";
int startIndex=0;
List<String> atoms=new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
    if (line.substring(i, i+1).equals(",")){
        atoms.add(line.substring(startIndex,i));
        startIndex=i+1;
    }
}
atoms.add(line.substring(startIndex,line.length()));
```

Comment: I modified my solution by using substring instead of split

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String a = new String("blue, small, 15, orange, large, 10, green, small, 5");
    String b[] = a.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        System.out.println(b[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use the Split function

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

You can easily use as

```
String []individualStrings = combinedString.split(",");
```